# Converting a string into a double[][] - Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, double

Since Java [doesn't have an `eval()` module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196143/evaluating-string-to-double-array-java), and I want to write my own regex to parse strings into a `double[][]`, e.g.

[in]:

```
`{{1.23,8.4},{92.12,-0.57212}}`
`{{1.23,-8.4}, {-92.12,-0.57212}}`
```

[code]:

```
 double[][] xArr;
 // Somehow read the string into something like this:
 xArr = new double[][] {{1.23,8.4},{92.12,-0.57212}};
 System.out.println(xArr[0][0] + " " + xArr[0][1]);
```

[out]:

```
 1.23 -8.4
```

Currently, I'm doing it as such:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{{1.23,8.4}, {92.12,-0.57212}}";

        Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("((-)?\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
        Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
        List<double[]> locations = new ArrayList<double[]>();
        int i = 0;
        while(matcher.find()){
            double d1 = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
            matcher.find();
            double d2 = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
            locations.add(new double[] {d1, d2});
            i++;        
        }; 


    }

}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I.e.:

- Now, the code is sort of cheating by know that my inner size of the double[][] is 2 and during iteration through `match.find()`. It does 2 passes to skip to the next pair, **is there a way to change the regex such that it extracts 2 groups at a time?**
- Currently it's reading into the `d1` and `d2` variable before create a new `double[]` to add to the `List`, **is there a way to do it directly without creating `d1` and `d2`?**

Comment: If you don't care about performance you could use a Javascript engine in Java, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605051/2947592

Comment: @wvdz, how do you convert the resulting `Object` to `double[][]`?

Comment: What about using the `matcher.groupCount()` to find the size of the double array ?

Comment: You can cast it to `NativeArray` and then just manually convert it to a `double[][]`. I don't think it's the best approach, but might be easier then fixing your regex, if you just need a quick fix. I think using regex is nicer though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a Java 8 solution I came up with:

```
String test = "{{1.23,8.4},{92.12,-0.57212}}";

double[][] vals = Arrays.stream(test.replaceAll(" ", "").split("},\\{"))
                        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split(","))
                        .map(Arrays::stream)
                        .map(stream -> stream.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble)
                                             .toArray())
                        .toArray(double[][]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(vals));
```

Output:

```
[[1.23, 8.4], [92.12, -0.57212]]
```

Or if you want a `Double[][]`:

```
Double[][] vals = Arrays.stream(test.replaceAll(" ", "").split("},\\{"))
                        .map(str -> str.replaceAll("[{}]", "").split(","))
                        .map(Arrays::stream)
                        .map(stream -> stream.map(Double::parseDouble)
                                             .toArray(Double[]::new))
                        .toArray(Double[][]::new);
```

Explanation:

First any whitespace is removed and the string is split on the pattern `},\\{` which will result in a `String[]` where each `String` is one of the `double[]`s with some excess curly braces:

```
["{{1.23,8.4", "92.12,-0.57212}}"]
```

Then, for each `String` the curly braces are removed, and the `String` is split again. So each `String` becomes a `String[]` where each value is the `String` representation of a "`double`":

```
[["1.23", "8.4"],["92.12", "-0.57212"]]
```

These strings are then parsed into doubles, and everything is collected into a `double[]` and then a `double[][]`:

```
[[1.23, 8.4], [92.12, -0.57212]]
```

Comment: I'm getting `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to double[][]` on `Arrays.deepToString(vals)`

Comment: @alvas Is your code exactly the same as my post? Because I have tested it and it works.

Comment: I have `Double[][] vals;` before doing the conversion. It's a variable that's declare way up in my code.

Comment: Ah, i got it, i had `double[][] locationArray = Arrays.deepToString(vals);` How do i get from `Double[][]` to `double[][]`?

Comment: Thanks!! Ah, I could change the type at the last conversion streaming =)

Comment: Could you also leave the answer for the type resulting in Double[][] too? I think i'll help others in the future =)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116491/discussion-between-explv-and-alvas).

Answer (score 6):

Use jackson but you will have to replace the braces  with boxes/parenthesis.

With this you don't need to specify the dimensions of the expected array

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String jsonString = "{{1.23,8.4}, {92.12,-0.57212}}";
    jsonString = jsonString.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]");
    Double[][] doubles = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Double[][].class);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(doubles));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Question:

   > is there a way to change the regex such that it extracts 2 groups at a time

Yes. You could extract a whole line with one pattern, by using your existing one. You have to add the paranthesis and the komma and a the + operator (for multiple values).
When you have a single line, you can extract the values with your current pattern, until there are no more found (with a while loop).

2. Question:

   > is there a way to do it directly without creating d1 and d2?

I don't know exactly what you mean. Where is the problem with creating them? With the suggested way on question 1, you could store every value directly in a list as well and hen create a array from it.

I like the solution of Olayinka, too if your format dont change.